# Links in the_content not linked

Tags: wp-query, the-content, single

I have alot of old posts that are being pulled with the_content() context.

In the_content() there is links in the text, however none of them are hyperlinked it just shows like http://twitter.com/twitterrocks with it not linked. Is there a way to link all links in my the_content() and make them target="_blank" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Running [make_clickable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Raeference/make_clickable) on the_content will get you your links. So...

`apply_filters('the_content','make_clickable');`

... in your `functions.php` should link your content. It will be simple but you should get hyperlinks.

I don't see a way to add the `target="_blank"` part. `make_clickable` is in [`wp-includes/formatting.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1547). You could use it as a pattern for a function that would add the `target="_blank"`.

Or you could force a jquery script to change all the links' targets to blank. Here's the code for that -

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').attr("target", "_blank");
</script>
```

Comment: The jQuery option was suggested by [kidakaka](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/15571/kidakaka)

Comment: except you don't want to include jQuery that way, you will break plugins that use it. Use WordPress's version via [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and note that WordPress jQuery is in [noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).

Comment: should be `apply_filters` instead of `apply_filter`, right?